# Expand the % register

Tags: vim

In insert or command mode typing `CTRL+r %` insert the name of the current file.

But is it possible to expand the % register so that it also contains the full path to the file?

Comment: Good question, might also be a fit for [vi SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's *command-line mode*, not "command mode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CTRL-R](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R) allows `=expression` "register". To insert full path use [`expand('%:p')`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expand()):

```
CTRL-R =expand('%:p')
```

Insert mode mapping:

```
:imap <C-R>p <C-R>=expand('%:p')<CR>
```

Press <kbd><C-R></kbd><kbd>p</kbd> in Insert mode.

Comment: Also `:help filename-modifiers`.

Comment: Thx, but I don't quite understand how to apply or use in the `.vimrc` file; could you please help out?

Comment: @KarlsD What do you want in `.vimrc`?

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean with this command and it really works. 
But I do not understand how to use it routinely, you suggest to press `CTRL+r` and then every time type `=expand('%:p')`?

cc @romainl

Comment: @KarlsD See the updated answer: I added Insert mode mapping `<C-R>p`. It can be added to `~/.vimrc`

Comment: Note that mapping `<C-r>p` is likely to prevent the insertion of register `p`.

Comment: @KarlsD Does the mapping help?